# ASP.NET controller gets called repeatedly by firefox if HttpStatusCodeResult has newlines in the description

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Let's assume we have a simple salt-of-the-earth mvc4-controller plus an action which returns a BadRequest response with a newline deliberately placed in the error description:

```
public class SaltOfTheEarthController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SimpleAction()
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "foo\nbar");
    }
}
```

We now invoke the above controller via jquery ajax like so:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/SaltOfTheEarth/SimpleAction",
        method: "GET"
    })
    .done(function() { console.log("** done"); })
    .fail(function () { console.log("** fail"); });
```

One would expect the asp.net infrastructure to readily detect the existence of the newline and intervene by throwing an argumentexception (due to the newline inside the status description) which would naturally result in an internalservererror response.

What happens instead (at least on the machine I'm testing all this out) is that the 'SimpleAction' method fails in a cryptic manner in the sense that the ajax response contains no headers or any other info whatsoever.

To make things even worst if the ajax call is performed by firefox then the controller-action gets called like 5+ times in a row repeatedly before firefox gives up (this second quirk doesn't happen with chrome though - the ajax call fails right off the bat).

Two questions:

- Since \n chars are causing so much trouble why doesn't the constructor of HttpStatusCodeResult (or some other internal cogwheel of asp.net) throw a fit when detecting \n chars in the response-headers fields? (maybe due to performance concerns?)
- Why does firefox retry the same action 10 times but chrome doesn't? What's the logic behind retrying?

Comment: To answer your sub questions: 1) It's not the framework's responsibility to handle this. 2) Given that the error that occurs is a "connection reset", it's possible Firefox is thinking that it's a temporary connection issue and retrying repeating to hopefully get a different response. However, probably only a member of the the Firefox dev team could give you an accurate answer.

Comment: "It's not the framework's responsibility to handle this" errr why? Is there some design spec that forbids the devs from going down that road by default? The framework is smart enough to intervene in other similar scenarios. Why not this one as well? Seems reasonable to me at least.